# Spacing between label and editfield in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, label, space, blackberry-editfield

Hi i just have an EditField instance that i created this way:

```
EditField editField = new EditField("Name", "");
```

But it shows that there is no space between the label "Name" and the  edit Field (fill form). I want to define a specific space between them but i wonder how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just give how much space u want in  "name" as "name       " like this

```
EditField editField = new EditField("Name     : ", "");
```